# How to add a file into zip?

Tags: zip, compression

I have a quite large zip file with archived documents and I want to add a new file into it.

How to do it quick and easy? The archive is quite large, so extract+add+compress+delete is not preffered option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK There's no (free) onboard app to achieve this.

The easiest way would be to do it via command line.

```
zip /path/to/zipfile.zip file1 file2
```

If you want to add all(!) files within a directory and subdirectories, run

```
zip -r /path/to/zipfile.zip /path/to/dir
```

It will also add `.DS_Store` files and that like, so be careful with the latter command.

However, if you're fine with spending some money, you could take a look at http://macitbetter.com. They provide an app called BetterZip 2 which is also capable of doing what you want.

Comment: Sad there is no native way in OS X, so lets go back to trees (and command line:)

Isn't it possible to create a service or whatever when I drag and drop file/folder to .zip to launch a command for me?

Answer (score 0):

For when you prefer a UI (versus command line), [Commander One](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/commander-one-file-manager/id1035236694?mt=12) providers a free UI for direct viewing and editing of ZIP files.